# RouterContext.push() reloads page on navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Here is my router config:

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <Route path="email" component={EmailPage}>
                <Route path="accountinfo" component={AccountInfo}/>
            </Route>
        </Route>
</Router>
```

In `EmailPage` I have this method:

```
class EmailPage {
  onEmailSubmit() {
    this.context.router.push('/email/accountinfo');
  }
}
```

The first time i submit, it reloads the whole page wiping out the state of the 'emailPage' component.

Using React router 2.0.0-rc4.  Am I doing something wrong?

Update:
I see that the url changes:

```
http://localhost:8080/#/email/?_k=1w69uj

to 
http://localhost:8080/?#/email/accountinfo?_k=ezdjg6

instead of 
http://localhost:8080/#/email/accountinfo?_k=ezdjg6
```

Note the missing additional `?` before `#` which seems to be causing the reload

Comment: I haven't used `hashHistory` much.. can you navigate around with `window.location.hash = '/email/accountinfo'`

Comment: added more details to the question. does that help?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: chrome 47. also tried on Edge. same results

Comment: it seems firefox 43 is the only place it works as expected. both chrome and edge seem to run into this issue

Comment: I know this doesn't solve your specific issue, but if you're not targeting older browsers, maybe try out `browserHistory`? It makes for far nicer URLS =/

Comment: seems to happen with `browserHistory` too. video here http://screencast.com/t/PLWsYI6JD. eventual 404 is cause server is not configured to handle browserHistory url refreshes

Comment: I am still having this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem once..
Take this for example..

```
  getRef(ref) {
    this.placeRef = ref;
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e);
    var place = this.placeRef.value;
    this.placeRef.value = '';
    this.context.router.push('/place/'+place);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="search">
        <form onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
          <div id="input_place">
            <input type="text" className="design" ref={(ref) => this.getRef(ref)} />
          </div>
          <div id="place_search">
            <button type='submit' className="design">Search</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

In `handleSubmit()` function if you remove `e.preventDefault()` then a full page reload will happen.
So i guess that might be a solution for your problem.